R and/or RStudio bug? Different whitespace causing execution errors
I am running a MacBook Pro, 14-inch, 2023, with M3 Pro chip, 18GB of RAM, and MacOS Sonoma 14.5. On top of that, I have R version 4.4.1, and RStudio version 2024.04.2+764. That is, as of this writing, I am running the latest version of all software.
Now I am running into an issue where if I format R code with different whitespace, I am getting syntax/execution errors. Here's a MWE:
if (0 < 1) {
    print("0 < 1")
} else {
    print("Weird alternate universe.")
}

This code runs exactly as expected when I click the "Source" button and when I put the cursor at the beginning of the file and click the "Run" button. However, if I format the whitespace according to my preferences, like this:
if (0 < 1) 
{
    print("0 < 1")
}
else 
{
    print("Weird alternate universe.")
}

RStudio complains that there is a syntax error on the else line, and if I click the "Source" button, it complains about the same thing. Oddly enough, if I put the cursor at the beginning of the file and click the "Run" button, it shows me this:
> if (0<1)
+

as if it's expecting more input.
It was not my understanding that R was as sensitive to whitespace (otherwise why bother with curly braces around the code segments?) as Python is, but this is bizarre. I have tried uninstalling all R software - R, packages, and RStudio, and starting over from scratch, but the problem did not go away.
What's going on, here?
[EDIT] The main difference appears to be that the else line doesn't seem to want to be on a different line than the curly brace immediately preceding it. That is,
if (0 < 1)
{
    print("0 < 1")
} else
{
    print("Weird alternate universe.")
}

executes correctly, with only the difference between this code and my preferred formatting is that the else is on the same line as the immediately preceding closing brace.

This is not about RStudio. Answers shouldn't be included in questions.

Apparently, this is part of R syntax, as evidenced by this link, and the following text at that link:

The else clause is optional. The statement if(any(x <= 0)) x <- x[x <= 0] is valid. When the if statement is not in a block the else, if present, must appear on the same line as the end of statement2. Otherwise the new line at the end of statement2 completes the if and yields a syntactically complete statement that is evaluated. A simple solution is to use a compound statement wrapped in braces, putting the else on the same line as the closing brace that marks the end of the statement.


That's right.  Think of it this way: if there is no else, then if (condition) {; <some staements>;} is valid.  R checks at the end of each line if it has a valid statement.  if it does, it executes it.  The code I've just given is valid.  So R executes it.  (And forgets about it.)  Now R moves to the next line of input.  It finds an else, but doesn't have an if to pair it with.  Hence the error.  On the other hand, ``if (condition) {;;} else; is not (yet) valid, so R continues to parse and no error occurs.

@Limey we cannot tell where your new lines are in your code examples

@stefan_aus_hannover: that’s what the semi-colons are for. :-). But it seems I did miss a couple of backticks. Sorry about that.

R looks for the opening curly bracket on the same line as the IF or ELSE. Its R syntax rules.
This example WORKS for me:
if (0 < 1) {
  print("0 < 1")
} 
else {
  print("Weird alternate universe.")
}

Yields
[1] "0 < 1"

EDIT
This does NOT work for me
if (0 < 1) {
  print("0 < 1")
} else
{
  print("Weird alternate universe.")
}

It yields
> if (0 < 1) {
+   print("0 < 1")
+ } else
+

I am running RSTUDIO on Windows 11

Ok, so why does this work also:
if (0 < 1) 
{
    print("0 < 1")
} else 
{
    print("Weird alternate universe.")
}


Sorry, formatting doesn't work in the comments. If you put the else on the same line as the preceding closing brace, and put the next opening brace on a newline, it still works.

Are you saying your code does not execute? Because it doesn't execute on my Mac or my Linux machine.

@AdrianKeister edited above

Your second code chunk works for me (in the terminal).

@BenBolker I stated in my post where i ran the code.

@AdrianKeister if you run the code in RSTUDIO and do NOT select the whole if else, what is the result????
